# Create statement doesn't work with four constraints but works with two?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-design

I'm trying to debug a problem with a create statement I have however the error message doesn't really make any sense.

The script is:

```
CREATE TABLE    marlin.SupportLog
(
    IssueID             INTEGER         UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    TypeID              INTEGER         NOT NULL ,
    IssueDescription    VARCHAR(5000)   NOT NULL ,
    MinutesSpent        INTEGER         NOT NULL ,
    PriorityID          INTEGER         NOT NULL ,
    UserID              INTEGER         NOT NULL ,
    SubmittedDate       DATETIME        NOT NULL    DEFAULT SYSDATETIME() ,
    LastModifiedDate    DATETIME        NULL        DEFAULT SYSDATETIME() ,
    LastModifiedUserID  INTEGER         NULL

    CONSTRAINT  SupportLog_pk
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (IssueID)

    CONSTRAINT  TypeID_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (TypeID)
            REFERENCES  marlin.SupportIssueType(TypeID)

    CONSTRAINT  SLPriorityID_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (PriorityID)
            REFERENCES  marlin.SupportPriority(PriorityID)

    CONSTRAINT  UserID_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
            REFERENCES marlin.SupportUsers(UserID)
);
```

If I comment out the last two constraints the table works fine however if I run it as above I receive:

```
Msg 8148, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
More than one column FOREIGN KEY constraint specified for column 'LastModifiedUserID', table 'marlin.SupportLog'.
Msg 8148, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
More than one column FOREIGN KEY constraint specified for column 'LastModifiedUserID', table 'marlin.SupportLog'.
```

The error doesn't appear to help - what am I not understanding / what have I done wrong?

Comment: The error message does not fit the SQL?! Strange. Can you post the DML fot the other three tables so we can repro fully?

Comment: @JohnPick Oh, come on! Missing comma's it is. Such an ambiguous error message though! If you can post this as an answer I'll accept so you receive the appropriate reputation for it.

Comment: agreed. the error message was misleading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `CREATE TABLE` statement is missing a comma before each `CONSTRAINT`.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a table there are two ways of doing constraints. At the table level or at the column level. For example (using Oracle, no SQL Server handy, but they both have the same concept):

```
-- column level
create table t(c1 number constraint t_uk1 unique
    , c2 number constraint t_uk2 unique);

-- table level
create table t(c1 number
    , c2 number
    , constraint t_uk1 unique(c1)
    , constraint t_uk2 unique(c2));
```

What was happening, in your case, without the commas, was that you had multiple column level constraints against the last column in your table. I agree that the message was not helpful. SQL Server was guessing a different meaning from what you intended.

Note: One must use table constraints when multiple columns are involved.

The column involved in a column level constraint is implicit. Presumably once SQL Server got past the multiple foreign key constraints on one column it would have started complaining about how columns specified different then the one it was complaining about where being specified.

More details can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx).